# I seem to have dissapearing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

ok thanks for the help everyone heres everything relevent that i can think of:

**gamemanager.h"**

```
#include "item.h"
#include "hero.h"

class gamemanager
{
    public:
        void acquireItems(hero player, item vendor);
};
```

**gamemanager.cpp:**

```
void gamemanager::acquireItems(hero player, item vendor)
{

    int choice;
    int choice2;
    cout<<"\nWould you like to buy 1.offense OR 2.defense : ";
    cin>>choice;


if(choice==1)
{
    cout<<"\nGood day sir, what can i do for you: \n1.Buy\n2.Sell\n3.Leave \n";
    cin>>choice2;

    if(choice2==1)
        {
            cout<<"\nThese are my wares today: "<<endl;

            int index;
            int select;
            int wep;
            char sel;

            index=rand()%vendor.Wname.size();

            if(index==0)
                ++index;

            for(wep=0; wep<index; wep++)
            {
                select = rand()%vendor.Wname.size();
                cout<<wep<<". "<<vendor.Wname[select]<<endl;
            }

            cout<<"\nEnter the number of item you want, or enter 'q' to exit"<<endl;
            cin>>sel;

            if(sel=='q')
                return;

            weapon* WEAPON = new weapon(vendor.Wname[wep]);
            player.inventory.push_back(WEAPON);

            player.setdefense();
        }
}
```

**hero.h**

```
class hero
{
    public:
        vector<item*> inventory;
        void setdefense();
};
```

**hero.cpp**

```
    void hero::setdefense()
{
    if(inventory.size()!=0)
    {
        for(unsigned int x=0; x<inventory.size(); x++)
        {
            m_defense = m_defense + inventory[x]->getbonus();
        }
    }
}
```

**main():**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gamemanager.h"
#include "hero.h"
#include "enemy.h"
#include "item.h"

int main()
{
    gamemanager boss;
    item vendor;
    hero player(10, 20);

    boss.acquireItems(player, vendor);

    cout<<player.inventory.size()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Theres obviously alot more to the classes, but for the sake of size i took out irrelevent stuff.
And like i said when i cout inventories size in main(), it prints out zero, also player is an instance of class hero created in main()

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted - did you leave anything out?

Comment: "as soon as it hits main()"?! What do you mean? `main` is the first thing that runs (other than static field initializers).

Comment: Please show more code, maybe your complete code.

Comment: I think you should show your main() code. How do you create and use "player"?

Comment: Please show the complete function where you push the item into the vector. I have a suspicion that `player` is a local variable in a function, and as an object it's destructor is called when the function returns. See also [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).

Comment: Shouldn't `weapon *WEAPON` be `WEAPON *weapon`?

Comment: @H2CO3 As you see, he has `= new weapon(...);`, so the class name is `weapon`.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn Sure, but it's quite a twisted naming convention to have a type in lowercase and a variable (!) name in all caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost certain this line is the culprit: you're passing the type `hero` by value. If you pass by reference it'll work like you expect it too.

```
void gamemanager::acquireItems(hero player, item vendor)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only two reasons:

1. You are accessing `player` before `push_back` happened or after someone called `pop_back` on it.
2. You are accessing different instance of `player` (say some local var)

If you can provide some more code operating on `player`, it will help answering.